# Spark on kubernetes how to bring back drivers in case of failures / restarts

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job which currently runs in cluster mode in Kubernetes. Drivers and executors run fine and I have no issues with them.

However when thinking about failures, how can the driver pod be secured from any k8s level node restarts.

Eg: In a scenario where the underlying worker node where the pod is running restarts or the driver dies for some reason how can we recover from that?

The behaviour I am looking for is similar to Deployments in K8S where kubernetes always honors the minimum number of replicas.

But when going through the spark on k8s documentation there is no such mention on anything related to this

So in brief: If my driver pod dies due to some issues, how can we tell kubernetes to automatically bring it back up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spark Operator](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spark-on-k8s-operator/docs/quick-start-guide.html) to run your job as a SparkApplication and specify a [restartPolicy](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spark-on-k8s-operator/docs/user-guide.html#configuring-automatic-application-restart-and-failure-handling).